# DB First The Generated context does not have constructor overload for connection string

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to set the connection string for my database at runtime.
Using the ADO.NET Entity data model to create my context from an existing database I get a context which requires the connection string to be in the app.Config.

I want to set this programmatically,  And I can do that by creating an overloaded constructor on the generated context and this works... until...

If I have to refresh my model from the DB,  this overloaded constructor is deleted and I have to add it back in.

Is there a way of configuring the T4 model generation such that it allows me to specify the connection string?

Answer (score 3):

I realised after posting this that the Context generated is a partial class,  So I created another code file with the appropriate constructor within and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it is not partial one. what could be the option in this regards. This class is from the metadata created by entity project using database first approach.

```
namespace Survey.Models
{
    public class NetpiperDBcontext : DbContext
    {
        public NetpiperDBcontext();

        public virtual DbSet<AnswerOption> AnswerOptions { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<Attachment> Attachments { get; set; }
        public virtual DbSet<AttributeIcon> AttributeIcons { get; set; }
    }
}
```